# Problem with the second part of the integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am supposed to calculate integral:
$$\int \frac{\sin x-\sin x\cdot\cos^{2}x}{\cos^{4}x+2\cos^{2}x+1}\,\mathrm dx$$
I calculated it till the point: $$-\int\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}\,dt + 2\int\frac{t^{2}}{\left ( t^{2}+1 \right )^{2} } \,dt$$ where $t=\cos(x)$.

I know that the first integral is equal to $$\arctan(t)+c $$
but I do not know how to calculte the second part. I did partial fractions, but it was not succesful.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use partial fraction to find out $\frac{t^2}{(t^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{t^2+1}-\frac{1}{(t^2+1)^2}$ can you continue from here? HINT for second partial part is to put $t=\tan(y)$ and then it's an easy integral.

Comment: So ,that the first integral is again arctg(t)+c and the second one is $$\frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{1}{t^{2}+1} \right )+c$$?

Comment: Please recheck the second integral

Comment: So, that is $$\int cos^{2}y.dy$$?

Comment: Yes that should be it.

Comment: okay, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the following derivative:
$$
\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2}\right)'=\frac{t^2+1-t(2t)}{(1+t^2)^2}=\frac{1-t^2}{(t^2+1)^2}
$$
Your integral was
$$
-\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}\mathrm{d}t+2\int\frac{t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\mathrm{d}t=\int\frac{t^2-1}{(1+t^2)^2}\mathrm{d}t=-\frac{t}{1+t^2}+C
$$
The last equality follows by the definition of the integral.